# Android Studio: I want my button to open the phone settings

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In my android studio app, java: When I click on my button, I want it to open the phones settings, for example the wi-fi settings. I assume it is going to be a path to settings but I cant find a way to do this.
Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start a new `Intent`. Here is an example to open the Wifi settings:

`startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));`

You get go through the `android.provider.Settings` constants for different settings that you can go to.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome. Glad I could help. Please accept my answers?